# Conceder permisos para android Marshmallow ( Android 6.0 )

Tags: android-studio, permisos

Estoy intentando otorgar los permisos en Android Marshmallow pero sigue sin funcionar. El código que he usado es éste:

```
  private  boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
      int pocatioPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS);
    int permi = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

    if (permi != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
    if (pocatioPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS);
    }

    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Pero en la consola me sigue apareciendo este error:

> was not granted  this permission: android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS

---

Muchas gracias por las respuestas, pero sigo sin consegir que funcione tengo puesto los permisos en el manifest y ahora e añadido el Settings.System.canWrite()
pero me sige dando el mismo error, lo raro es que cuando inicio la app deberian aparecerme las ventanitas para conceder los permisos y solo me aparece para el permiso WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE pero para el WRITE_SETTINGS no me muestra ninguna ventanita de conceder permisos.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español! Te sugiero que añadas toda la información que puedas ya que hasta ahora es escasa. Intenta hacer cuantas pruebas se te ocurran utilizando todas las herramientas de diagnóstico que puedas. Te puede orientar nuestra ayuda para saber [cómo completar tu pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Verifica que :

- Tienes `<uses-permission>` en tu manifest.
- Llama la funcion `Settings.System.canWrite()` para ver si esta apto para escribir.
- Si este ultimo evento devuelve falso :

  ```
  if (Settings.System.canWrite(context) {
          //Todo bien aqui
  } else {
      Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
      intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getActivity().getPackageName()));
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      startActivity(intent);
  }
  ```

La documentación de [ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS) dice que :

> ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS
>   Added in API level 23
>     String ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS
>   Activity Action: Show screen for controlling which apps are allowed to write/modify system settings.
>
> In some cases, a matching Activity may not exist, so ensure you safeguard against this.
>
> Input: Optionally, the Intent's data URI can specify the application package name to directly invoke the management GUI specific to the package name. For example "package:com.my.app".
>
> Output: Nothing.
>
> Constant Value: "android.settings.action.MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS"

Español (resumido) :

> Muestra la pantalla para controlar aquellas aplicaciones que pueden leer o modificar la configuracion del sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Asegura tener definido el permiso dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

y mediante [Settings.System.canWrite()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#canWrite%28android.content.Context%29) puedes verificar si tu app puede en realidad modificar los settings del sistema, revisa la documentación desde API 23 una aplicación no puede modificar los settings a menos que declares [WRITE_SETTINGS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_SETTINGS) en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
 boolean permission;
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            permission = Settings.System.canWrite(context);
        } else {
            permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        }
```